# Understanding the exact meaning of dB/decade in a Bode plot

Tags: filter

To make the question clear I will ask this with an example.

Let's say we have a LP filter with a **-3dB attenuation at cutoff frequency of 1kHz**.
And lets say we are given the steepness of the filter as **100 dB/decade**.

Does that mean the filter will attenuate 100 dB/decade **right after** -3dB point?

If so, the following possibilities for Bode plot points confuses me when I try to use dB/decade definition:

-103 dB at 10 kHz? or

-100 dB at 10 kHz? or

-100 dB at 11 kHz? or

-103 dB at 11 kHz? or

Which one of the above is exactly correct according to the definition dB/decade?
What confuses me is should we take decade as multiplication or addition to the cut off frequency? And should we go down from -3dB or zero for the attenuation?

Comment: It would be -100dB at 10kHz. The dB/decade is asymptotic.

Comment: Asymptotic isn't the word I would use.  "Piecewise linear approximation with a corner at the cutoff frequency" is a better description.

Comment: @ScottSeidman What I mean is that the actual behavior is asymptotic to the piecewise linear approximation. I did not really articulate that very well.

Comment: Any more questions?

Comment: @Hearth or ScottSeidman Can you write an answer what you mean graphically? I think you really understand what Im asking about. But I dont get by one sentence, an example on a plot helps. Thanks

Comment: @user1999 Look at the first graph in Andy's answer. The -100dB/decade is the blue line, while the red line is the actual filter response.

Comment: @Hearth what do you mean by asymptotic or piecewise linear in connection with the dB/decade? I need to see the relation graphically to understand.

Comment: @user1999 That graph in Andy's answer shows everything I'm talking about--what I mean by asymptotic is that the red line gets closer and closer to the blue line as the frequency goes further from the cutoff frequency. The blue line in Andy's graph is the piecewise linear approximation of the filter response.

Comment: I still dont think the answers are answering what Im asking about. Maybe the question is not clear enough

Comment: @user1999, here is a "correct" answer (because you wish an "exactly correct" answer): In your example, the slope of -100dB/dec will be (theoretically) reached at infinite frequncy only. But note that this is a value which is derived from mathematics only - and has nothing to do with real electronics (due to several disturbing influences and tolerances).

Comment: @LvW  Imagine in practice if I face a situation with a LP(Q<=0.5) filter given the 3dB cut-off freq. as 1kHz and 100dB per/decade information on a datasheet, and now if I want to roughly estimate the dB attenuation at lets say 4kHz how would you proceed? So in that case lineerizing the Bode plot  and from simple geometry I calculate the dB attenuation as a function of kHz frequency(where f>1kHz) as follows: dB_attenuation = 11.1*(f - 1). So to this equation if I plug f = 4kHz I find 33.3dB. Can we do that? If not, does that mean we cannot even make an estimate given the data I mentioned.

Comment: If you think this is another question I can open a new question as well.

Comment: Yes - that is another question. In your first contribution (problem decription) you spoke about an "exactly correct" answer - and now (in your comment) you want a "rough estimate".....I think, for such an estimate the asymptotic simplification is sufficient.

Comment: @user1999  Unless you know Q, 2f is hard to estimate but 4f is ok to estimate thus (order=) 5x -6dB/oct x 2 oct (=4f) = **-60dB** is closer.  and 10f is exact as I showed If you need more then choose a Chebychev or higher order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer**

```
n order fc=1kHz  10kHz   100kHz
1       -3dB    -20dB   -40dB  
2       -3dB    -40dB   -80dB
3       -3dB    -60dB  -120dB
4       -3dB    -80dB  -160dB
5       -3dB   -100dB  -200dB
```

**These are the exact values within 0.01 dB with parts with 0% tolerance error.**

The standard signal filter passband BW is defined by the -3dB BW.  The asymptotes go thru the flat intersection (e.g. 0dB)  but actual is shown above. These are not estimates but are using perfect parts.

**Details**

> The stopband attenuation vs frequency slope above cutoff (-3dB) attenuation [dB]\$ = -6n_{dB/octave f} = -20n  _{dB/decade}\$ per nth order of filter, where n is the number of independant reactors, ( here just the number of C's)

We can estimate the attenuation at 1 decade up to be pretty accurate and closer in as the shape factor by Q and order of filter > 1

However the maximally flat frequency only produces critical damping at 2nd order and higher orders have more ringing.

[image]

## For the advanced reader....

The above image shows two modes for both Bessel vs Butterworth:

1. Sine-wave input log-sweep with envelope response
2. Square-wave input at 80Hz while corner freq was 1kHz, to see the difference in damping & ringing.

   - Bessel is best in time-domain for zero overshoot but lowest Q or least steep corner frequency and thus lowest component tolerance sensitivity but also worst for image reject ratios for ADC near the corner. So it depends on your criteria.

Comment: Unfortunately, Bessel filters have not "this maximally flat response". Instead they are optimized for maximally flat group delay.

Comment: Sunnyskyguy, sorry to say, but many errors in your revised version (critically damping, shape factor, overshoot, overall Q, meaning of fc).

Comment: Both comments above apply to an earlier version of the answer.

Comment: @LvW I disagree "The question is how to interpret the meaning of dB/decade."  which is fundamentally clear only in my answer with the table.  (-1) for your negative bias contributions

Comment: what do you disagree with? I did not comment on your "table". And it was not me who downvoted your contribution (which, however, does not answer the question).

Comment: WHich question does the table not answer?   "should we take decade as multiplication or addition to the cut off frequency? And should we go down from -3dB or zero for the attenuation?"   the answers are obvious in my table. Anyone who votes -1 without asking for clarification because I assume they can add and subtract . TY

Comment: The table contains (vera rough) values which were derived from the asymptotes only. Not very helpful (in my view).

Comment: @LvW not true. If you hadn't been so critical on my other answers you would have seen it was 100 % accurate beyond your poor judgement> if you still doubt I can send the text results computed for each then I would expect you to retract and change your ways\/ if you were fair minded that is

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Can you help me with this question if possible  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/439615/how-are-and-what-are-the-sources-coupled-to-a-3-wire-rtd-leads

Comment: Sure , I see you cannot vote.   I also see @LVW still does not understand my table of values are actual, and not asymptotes, and thus accurate as well as useful and also verified by simulation. nor does he understand how to correct his comments

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy You are in error - I understand your table but the given (theoretical) figures are derived from the asymptotic lines only and, hence, do not answer the original question. I think, the questioner needs to understand the difference between actual damping and the simplification provided by the asymptotic lines. Therefore, he is asking for "exactly correct" values. Example: A first order lowpass with fc=1 kHz will exhibit at 10kHz a slope less than -20dB/dec (and will have an attenuation less than 20 dB).

Comment: @LVW the table was computed with 0.1dB accuracy by TI’s software. Your oversight . Theses are exact correct values. You misread. The asymptotes intersect at -3dB actual values regardless of order . These were not asymptotic estimates but real values foR every order I computed . Not your wrong misunderstanding .  These used ideal part values. Try again

Comment: I don’t see how anyone could be more concise and precise than the table I computed yet you downvoted and misunderstood.

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy, no doubt about it - the difference is rather small (surprisingly, I am able too to perform calculations), but it was my impression that the questioner wants to see the difference between real and asymptotic values. Example: with fc=1kHz the damping at 10 kHz is - 20.043 dB (and not -20 dB as provided by the asymptotic lines). Of course, in reality this difference plays no role, but I have tried to react upon the question as exact as possible - thats all!

Comment: @LVW perhaps I saw it as nitpicking, because although I used integer like the OP, , they were "exact" (to 0.01dB), not asymptote or estimates., which answered  fundamentally **is it -103 dB at 10 kHz? or -100?** concisely, but we had a communication gap, it seems    -3 dB actual vs  0 dB what you read

Comment: OK - I must admit that i did not recognize your comment ("..exact within 0,01 db...")

Comment: @LVW OK I added that for anyone who thought it was derived from asymptotes like yourself rather than actual values.  The major exclusions from this table occur due the curve shape between fc and 2fc which was not asked nor did I explain.  But by filter design constraints fc== -3dB is the standard, (i.e. half power point) although you and I know, one can define the passband or cuttoff differently like Bessel to -12 dB with 0.1 dB ripple in the passband.

Comment: Yes - I agree. The passband of any filter can be arbritrarily defined - depending on the specific application requirements. In some cases, the passband can even be defined in the time domain (group delay requirements in Thomson-Bessel filters).

Answer (score 4):

Look at this filter - it has 20 dB per decade roll-off: -

[image]

So, you can choose to use either the real graph of the filter (in red) or use the simpler straight line approximations where the worst error you will get is 3.01 db. This assumes that the damping ratio of the filter is \$\sqrt{0.5}\$.

If you have a filter that is under-damped compared to the above it might produce a peak in the response close to the cut-off frequency and so you have to decide on the merits of simplicity versus accuracy: -

[image]

Q is inversely proportional to damping ratio (\$\zeta\$) and, as you should be able to see, apart from critical frequencies around the cut-off point, the straight line approximation holds reasonable for various damping ratios.

To answer your question, the attenuation at 10 kHz is approximately 100 dB.

> Does that mean the filter will attenuate 100 dB/decade right after
>   -3dB point?

No, it doesn't - it will attenuate only at this rate as the red line in the graph above starts to merge into the blue line but there will always be a small error. The red line is the real characteristic and the blue line is a useful engineer's approximation to the characteristic.

Comment: Im asking something different and more fundamental. The question is how to interpret the meaning of dB/decade. Thats why I gave those examples in question. Could you also give some hint related to the comments under the question? I dont get what they mean. But have a feeling that the comments are directly related to the reason behind why the answer is 10kHz 100dB. Ignoring the accuracy for now and considering a 1st order LP for ease.

Comment: 1st order -20dB/decade or -20dB at 10fc , -40dB at 100fc -60B at 1e3 Hz

Comment: @Andy aka, I have spent some minutes (or more) thinking about your new finding regarding the product of all pole-Qs for Butterworth. I am afraid, it is not too easy to explain the math behind this. I think, it is because (a) the poles are always equally distributed along the unit circkle

Comment: (continued) ...and (b) the pole-Q is directly related to the real part of the pole [1/2cos(phi)]. Hence, the product of two Qs involves the product of cos(x)cos(y), which can be expressed by cos(x-y) + cos(x+y). I have checked this for n=4 - and it works. For larger n values it becomes rather complicated. I must admit, I was really surprised about your finding....I could not find any mentioning  of this Butterworth property in textbooks.

Comment: @LvW I used a spreadsheet and altered n in even numbers and let excel do the hard work. It's probably as tricky to prove as the original butterworth idea!

Comment: Nice info Andy.  But if -3.01 dB= \$\zeta=\sqrt{0.5}=0.707\$ is it consistent with Q graph= 0.707  if \$1\\zeta =Q\$. Are you saying Q=gain. I though gain differs at low values from geometric-reasons.  “apparent”  vs tangents X/R

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 for a 2nd order filter, at \$\omega_n\$ the amplitude is Q. If you use the standard H(s) formula for a 2nd order filter and equate \$\omega\$ to \$\omega_n\$ then it all drops out to be Q. Maybe scroll down to this heading (QUALITY FACTOR, AMPLITUDE AND PHASE AT ωn) on [this page](http://stades.co.uk/index.html)

Comment: right \$Q=\dfrac{X(f)}{Xc(f)+R}= \dfrac{1}{2ζ}\$  ok we agree  Yet for BPF we always define \$Q=f/\Delta f_{-3dB}\$ regardless of the order of the filter yet @LVW says we cannot define a mean or overall Q for a filter with variable Q's for each stage which seems inconsistent.  I guess the BPF method of estimating Q is incorrect or only applies to 2nd order

Comment: Defining Q as F/BW is problematic because of the asymmetry of the BW when the frequency is low. This is because the higher 3 dB point may be at (say) 2.F whereas the lower 3 dB point must be at F/2. I never meaningfully use Q = F/BW for that reason.

Comment: Is it because |amplitude gain| and Q are not the same for low values. At one time I always assumed  \$Q= =\dfrac{X(f_o)}{R}\$ instead of above.

Comment: For a high-Q filter it becomes a better approximation. For higher orders than 2 then Q becomes meaningless given that it is tied to zeta and zeta only has meaning for a 2nd order equation. The deeper you delve the more subtlety there is!!